# Почему не отображаются иконки с градиентом из SVG спрайта?

Tags: html, вёрстка, svg, svg-спрайт

коллеги.
Прошу вас помогите решить вопрос об отображении иконки из спрайта с градиентом.

САБЖ: Есть сайт, где часть иконок вызывается из файла спрайта, а часть инлайнится, т.к. я не могу заставить их нормально отрисовываться из спрайта.
[Сайт](https://zzfox.org/fake-site/shablon_cms/)

Есть собственно файл спрайта, где все иконки залиты однообразно через symbol.
[Sprite file](https://zzfox.org/fake-site/shablon_cms/img/icon/sprite.svg)

В нем есть иконка с id=star, у нее есть градиент.

ПРОБЛЕМА: при ее вызове в разметке я вижу, что иконка отрисовалась, но ее заливка - нет. Т.е. она просто не видна на странице ни в одном браузере. Это при том, что еще более сложные иконки спокойно отрисовалсиь и видны.

Как я вызываю иконку:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <use xlink:href="/img/icon/sprite.svg#star"></use>
</svg>
```

Ее код в спрайте

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" fill="none">
<symbol viewBox="0 0 100 100" id="star">
<path d="M100 50c0 27.614-22.386 50-50 50S0 77.614 0 50 22.386 0 50 0s50 22.386 50 50z" fill="url(#0_linear)"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M50.794 21.773l7.195 20.687h20.084l-16.36 12.724 7.288 21.865-18.207-13.656-18.208 13.656 7.288-21.865-16.36-12.724h20.084l7.196-20.687zm0 7.248L45.29 44.84H30.454l12.212 9.498-5.41 16.231 13.538-10.153L64.332 70.57l-5.41-16.23 12.212-9.499H56.296l-5.503-15.82z" fill="url(#1_linear)"/>
<defs>
<linearGradient id="0_linear" x1="47.246" y1="112.859" x2="124.114" y2="17.489" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><stop stop-color="#EEE8FF"/>
<stop offset="0" stop-color="#EEE8FF"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#FFF5FF"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="1_linear" x1="49.291" y1="84.156" x2="91.895" y2="31.984" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="#A046FF"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#FF00FB"/>
</linearGradient>
</defs>
</symbol>
</svg>
```

Прошу коллег указать мне, что я делаю не так.
Заранее благодарю!!!

Comment: @MaximLensky: как это нету? Всё норм.

Comment: Как по мне, так проблема в дублировании градиентов и одинаковых ID в svg-файле.

Comment: @UModeL Не... Тут какая-то более сильная магия. Ставлю уникальные ID - и все равно без ответа... Ковыряю... Наковыряю - отпишу в тему...

Comment: @Polina я ночью смотрел у вас был url такой icon/sprite.svg#star но не было самого спрайта в папке  icon

Comment: @Polina: а если просто в кодепен вставить код из svg-файла, то работает всё без ошибок?